# Require resolves undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, require

I have the following class structure.

### EmployeeService.js

```
const {EmployeeRequestExecutor} = require('./EmployeeRequestExecutor');

class EmployeeService {
    fulfill(request){
        EmployeeRequestExecutor.delegateEmployeeRequest(request);
    }
}

module.exports = {EmployeeService};
```

### EmployeeRequestExecutor.js

```
const {HelpfulEmployee} = require('./HelpfulEmployee');

class EmployeeRequestExecutor {
    static delegateEmployeeRequest(request){
        let employee = new HelpfulEmployee();
        employee.work(request);
    }

    static executeEmployeeRequest(request){
        console.log('Executed', request);
    }
}

module.exports = {EmployeeRequestExecutor};
```

### HelpfulEmployee.js

```
const {EmployeeRequestExecutor} = require('./EmployeeRequestExecutor');

class HelpfulEmployee {
    work(request){
        EmployeeRequestExecutor.executeEmployeeRequest(request);
    }
}

module.exports = {HelpfulEmployee};
```

If we then do

```
let employeeService = new EmployeeService();
employeeService.fulfill(request);
```

we get
TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeEmployeeRequest' of undefined in HelpfulEmployee.js:5:33

Why is it so that with such call structure `EmployeeRequestExecutor` inside `HelpfulEmployee.js` is undefined?

Comment: you might have a circular dependencies here `executeEmployeeRequest`-> `HelpfulEmployee`->`executeEmployeeRequest` and so on. You should fix that before going foward.

Comment: Could it be that the EmployeeService class expects a constructor? Just a wild guess. The exports seem fine to me otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a circular dependency between HelpfulEmployee and EmployeeRequestExecutor (they both require each other).
Circular dependencies result most of the time from class design issues. To fix them, you should reconsider the flow of information between your objects.

This is an option, but there are many more:

```js
const {HelpfulEmployee} = require('./HelpfulEmployee');

class EmployeeRequestExecutor {
    static delegateEmployeeRequest(request){
        let employee = new HelpfulEmployee();
        let requestExecutor = new EmployeeRequestExecutor();
        employee.work(request, requestExecutor);
    }

    executeEmployeeRequest(request){
        console.log('Executed', request);
    }
}

module.exports = {EmployeeRequestExecutor};
```

```js
class HelpfulEmployee {
    work(request, requestExecutor){
        requestExecutor.executeEmployeeRequest(request);
    }
}

module.exports = {HelpfulEmployee};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the final purpose of this architecture, to remove the `circular dependency` @Nicolas already mentioned, one option is to instantiate and provide the employee from the service to the executor as:

```
const { EmployeeRequestExecutor } = require("./EmployeeRequestExecutor");
const { HelpfulEmployee } = require("./HelpfulEmployee");

class EmployeeService {
  fulfill(request) {
    let employee = new HelpfulEmployee();
    EmployeeRequestExecutor.delegateEmployeeRequest(employee, request);
  }
}

module.exports = { EmployeeService };
```